# Magento-Imported products, but the price was not in the database field

Tags: magento

Imported products, but the price was not in the database field, resulting in product can not be displayed, I need help, thank you.

I found the required fields to be:

`store, websites, attribute_set, type, sku, name, price, description, short_description, tax_class_id, weight`

other:

`is_in_stock, qty, status, visibility`

Comment: Please advice how you are importing the products. Is that using Dataflow profiles or Import Products functionality

Comment: Yes, I want to import a simple product, but the product can not be displayed in the management, I think it is not a lack of the necessary fields? Thank you

Comment: http://temp-share.com/show/dPfsm3o5W please use this format for upload product

Answer (score 0):

Hi same problem i have facing please check these column are added in your csv file because these are also compulsory, When we import product using csv file.

[image: 1st columns]

Answer (score 0):

Also check these column status = Enable, visibility = Catalog, Search and tax class = None.

store id very must for appearing product on fronted

[image]